# How in general can I find functions that contains bugs due to array output?

Tags: powershell

Unassigned variables are outputted in PowerShell functions. So for instance in the function below you will get an object array returned instead of a string because [regex] is unassigned and needs to become assigned or nullified or whatever.

These bugs are very hard to detect when scanning codebases. Since some functions DO output an object array willingly (and then correctly handled) while for others it is indeed a bug. In this case the output was used to write somewhere and since an array gets transformed to a string it was undetectable.

```
    function Get-PascalizedString {
    param(
        [string]$String
    )
    $rx = "(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?<first>[a-zA-Z0-9])(?<reminder>[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*)"
    $result = ""
    [regex]::Matches($String, $rx) | ForEach-Object {$_.Groups} {
        $TextInfo = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
        $part = $TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Value.ToLower()).Trim()
        $part = $part -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
        $result = $result + $part
    }
    return $result
}

$a = Get-PascalizedString -String "aaa"
write-host $a
$a.GetType() // but...
```

So is there a smart way to detect these kind of bugs in larger codebases?

Comment: Write a test for it.

Comment: Thats probably the only way

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://mathieubuisson.github.io/create-custom-rule-psscriptanalyzer/).  You may be able to devise a way either by using PSScriptAnalyzer or coming up with something similar,  https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/ScriptRuleDocumentation.md

Comment: Using [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester): `$a | Should -HaveCount 1`. This works, because even single objects have a `Count` member that is 1.